# How to select only one column in a table using jQuery UI selectable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectable

What I am trying to do is allow the user to select rows from a single column at a time using jQuery UI selectable.

What I need to do though is restrict the drag/highlight effect from spanning more than one column. E.g. which ever column the user start the drag event in they cant highlight out side that column.

Table code

```
<table id="selectable">
  <tr>
    <td data-col="0">
    <td data-col="1">
    <td data-col="2">
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-col="0">
    <td data-col="1">
    <td data-col="2">
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-col="0">
    <td data-col="1">
    <td data-col="2">
  </tr>
  ...etc
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
var currentCol;

$("#selectable").selectable({
    filter:'td',
    selecting: function(event, ui){
        console.log($(ui.selected));
    }
});
```

But I cant access the value of `data-col`, it's always `null`.

Comment: you should provide relevant code

Comment: Instead of "this.getAttribute("data-col")" you should try the jQuery version $(this).attr('data-col')

Comment: That still returns undefined. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel for pointing me in the right direction.

In order to lock the drag down top a single column, this is what I did.

```
    var currentCol;

    $("#selectable").selectable({
        filter: "td",
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $("td").removeClass("ui-selected");
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {

            //Reset selector. 
            currentCol = undefined;
        },
        selecting: function(event, ui) {

            if (currentCol === undefined) {
                currentCol = $(ui.selecting).attr('data-col');
            }

            var nthChild = parseInt(currentCol) + 1; //Add one as nthChild is not zero index

            for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {

                if (i != nthChild) {
                    $("td.ui-selecting:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("ui-selecting");
                    });
                }
            }
            ;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you care about is the column index, this should work to get it:

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    filter: "td",
    selecting: function(event, ui) {
        console.log($(ui.selecting).prevAll().length);   
    }
});
```

Also `$(ui.selecting).attr('data-col')` should work if you still want to use that method.  In your example, you're using `ui.selected` where you should be using `ui.selecting`.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcPP3/)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can use the JQuery selector `td:nth-child($column_index)` (the index start from 1)

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    filter: "td:nth-child(1)",
    selecting: function (e, ui) {
         $(ui.selecting).css({'border':'1px solid black'})
    },
    unselecting: function (e, ui) {
         $(ui.unselecting).css({ 'border': '' })
    }
});
```